# CKEditor for iOS 8.0 Can't load JavaScript files

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ckeditor

I've been struggling for several days to incorporate the CKEditor into iOS 8.0 inside an UIWebView. Any help appreciated.

I have an empty project and added this code.

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    [self loadWebViewFromFile];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.


}

-(void)loadWebViewFromFile {
    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 500)];

    NSString *jsFile = @"ckeditor.js";
    NSString *jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsFile ofType:nil];
    NSURL *jsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jsFilePath];
    NSString *javascriptCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsURL.path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCode];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

}

@end
```

Resulting Screen Capture:
[Simulator for iPhone 6 - Deployment Target 9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUR6d.png)

Added CKEditor to Support Files directory.
[Added CKEditor to Support Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLfMf.png)

When I load it in the Safari Browser, it is fine. And this is what I want for my WebView.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor Sample</title>
    <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="main">




<main>

    <div class="adjoined-bottom">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-width-100">
                <div id="editor">
                    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                    <p>I'm an instance of <a href="http://ckeditor.com">CKEditor</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>

<script>
    initSample();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try evaluating your javascriptCode after loading the htmlString in your webView

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCode];
```

Comment: I have added that code, however the result is still the same. And no errors are in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem.

I decided instead to use the WKWebView.

Below is my code.

```
-(void)adjustWebView {

    // Load foundation HTML of webView

    // Test loading website URL:
    //    [self webViewLoadURL:@"http://www.apple.com"];

    // Loading website File:
    [self webViewLoadHTMLFile:@"defaultEditor"];

    self.webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;

}

-(void)webViewLoadURL:(NSString *)string {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

}

-(void)webViewLoadHTMLFile:(NSString *)filename {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"html"];
    NSString * stringHTML;

    @try {

        stringHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:stringHTML baseURL:nil];

    } @catch (id exception) {

        stringHTML = nil;

    }
}
```